# Yii2 Customized Flash Message, Doesn't Accept Array?

Tags: php, yii2

Is there any particular reason this flash message array works but for some reason it creates a flash message for every parameter in the array. This meaning is will echo a flash message for type, duration, icon, etc..

```
Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', [
'type' => 'success',
'duration' => 12000,
'icon' => 'fa fa-users',
'message' => 'My Message',
'title' => 'My Title',
'positonY' => 'top',
'positonX' => 'left'
```

]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setFlash http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#setFlash()-detail   set a flash message and if  there is already an existing flash message with the same key, it will be overwritten by the new one.

Seems the sintax of setFlash is not for array .. but you can use addFlash http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#addFlash()-detail

and add key pair value for future use  .. and retreive the value with getFlash() method

Comment: Aah I am able to use setFlash but I was keeping the identified as success on all messages. Changing it made it a separate flash message. Thank you very much for the help!